# How to add strick notes?

Tags: android, mupdf

I searched a lot, but didn't find any relevant way, link or hint to achieve this feature.

Can someone share some idea on how to achieve the aforementioned functionality?

It will be of great help to me.

Thanks ~

Comment: I'm not sure what 'strick notes' are? Can you give a link / example that shows what you want?

Comment: Sticky Notes -> http://bugs.ghostscript.com/attachment.cgi?id=11190

I hope you can help me solve it.

Thanks...

Comment: @Johns did u found any solution...?