# How to get author of a pdf document with mupdf

Tags: pdf, mupdf

how can I get metadata of a pdf document(e.g. title, author, creation date etc) by using mupdf library? There is not enough documentation to find out this functionality. Comments are not sufficient, too. Most probably, there is a functionality for this purpose but it is hard to find under these circumstances. The following code is what I have so far.

```
char info[64];
globals *glo = get_globals(env, thiz);

fz_meta(glo->doc, FZ_META_INFO, info, sizeof(info));
```

I have used `FZ_META_INFO` tag, but it doesn't work. I didn't get any info, just empty. I have checked that it has metadata. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

Target Android sdk:20

Min Android sdk:15

Mupdf version: 1.6

ndk: r10c

Development OS: Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In what sense 'doesn't work' ? Throws an error ? Crashes ? Are you certain the PDF file you are using has any 'Info' metadata ?

What is the version of MuPDF ? What platform are you using ?

You need to set the relevant key in the buffer you pass to fz_meta *before* you call fz_mets, I notice you aren't doing that.

See win_main.c at around line 487, after you get past the macro this resolves to

```
char info[256]

sprintf(info, "Title");
fz_meta(doc, FZ_META_INFO, info, 256);
```

On return 'info' will contain the metadata associated with the Title key in the dictionary.

When in doubt, build the sample app and follow it in a debugger......

Comment: From your answer, I understand, `sprintf(info, "Title");` sets the key in buffer. I tried it, but nothing changed. Still empty string returns. I looked at win_main.c, but I haven't found any related lines for my case. I will go for an eclipse for deeper debugging purpose, even though I use Android studio, but further information for this problem is appreciated.

Comment: The buffer you send to fz_meta, when using the FZ_META_INFO enum, must be initialised with the key associated with the data that you want to retrieve from the Info dictionary in the input PDF. I take it you are aware of PDF structure ? So you know that the Info dictionary may contain certain keys which are used to retrieve specific metadata ? Perhaps if you shared the PDF file you are testing with I could be more specific. I don't see why you can't find relevant code in win_main.c, there is a macro called SETUTF8 which retrieves the information using fz_meta.

Comment: +1 for this great answer. But there is an issue here. In file `pdf-xref.c`, under function `pdf_meta`, in case `FZ_META_INFO` , `info = pdf_dict_gets(info, *(char **)ptr);` results a fatal problem when I pass `info` array. into `fz_meta` function `(Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x6c746954 in tid 29833)`. I have change the line with `info = pdf_dict_gets(info, (char *)ptr);` and it works. If this is a bug, a bug report should be filled.

Comment: @KenS i'm using mupdf 1.7 but it doesn't has FZ_META_INFO. What shall i do..?

Comment: The interface has changed. Either read the change log or follow the suggestion I made; build the sample application and follow what it does in a debugger.

Comment: @KenS i read the change log where i can see we can able to get the author and title. is that so..?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a MuPDF developer. I know the interface changed, I'm assuming its been documented. If not then I'd suggest you build the demo viewer for your preferred platform and debug it, the demo viewer retrieves the metadata and sisplays it.

Comment: In case you find it hard, this is done in (at least) win_main.c, look for '#define SETUTF8'. The macro calls 'fz_lookup_metadata' to retrieve the information.

Comment: @KenS https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26033581/how-to-add-strick-notes.. can u please help us.

Comment: @KenS i cannot get meta information of epub any idea on this...?

Comment: No. "I am not a MuPDF developer". In addition I don't know anything about ePub.

Answer (score 0):

If the proper casting allow to send the key, 
this casting is NOT correct to receive back a char*.

Exemple;
Proper casting to send a request

```
char buff[2048];
strcpy(buff,"CreationDate")
if (fz_meta(ctx,doc,FZ_META_INFO,&buff,2048)) {
    buff[0] = 0;
}
```

Will: 
find the key, 
convert utf8 
then will crash when copyback of the result

Proper casting to receive a request

```
char buff[2048];
strcpy(buff,"CreationDate")
if (fz_meta(ctx,doc,FZ_META_INFO,buff,2048)) {
    buff[0] = 0;
}
```

Will crash during dict scanning.
looks really like a bug!
I confirm that modifying original source

```
info = pdf_dict_gets(ctx, info, (char *)ptr);
```

is the way to go. (even if strange that nobody else find it while writing code, because Meta are useful features frequently used